# Blender bevel modifier odd artifact

Tags: bevel, artifacts

Does anyone know how to fix this artifact issue caused by the bevel modifier? I have normals hardened and the bevel is weighted not angled.[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here's the link https://we.tl/t-6Grc65a1WM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by your bevel, there's a slight bevel weight on your edge, if you apply the *Bevel* modifier you can see what it gives. It creates a ngon and therefore this artefact:

[image]

You can use this topology instead:

[image]

Comment: is there an "easy fix" or would I have to convert the geo to quads/tris? I was planning on uploading it to substance and if im not mistaken substance painter triangulates your objects

Comment: with the Bevel modifier there may be a way but I don't know it, I personally prefer to create real bevel, see my edit

Comment: alright, thanks